# Maclauren Series and taylor polynomials

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, integration, taylor-expansion

Question:

Suppose that the function $k(x)$ has a maclauren series that converges $\left(-\frac{1}{2} , \frac{1}{2}\right]$ and you are told that  $|k^{(n)}(x)| \leq 10$ at all  $|x| \leq  \frac{1}{2}$ and all $n$. What is the degree of the smallest Taylor polynomial we can use to approximate $k(x)$ if we want the error to be less than $0.1$?

I'm very confused about this question and would like a hint please.

Answer (score 1):

The error for the Taylor polynomial approximation will be $\le M*[(1/2)^{(n+1)}]/(n+1)!$ where n is the degree of the Taylor polynomial used for the approximation and M is the maximum value of the (n+1)st derivative of k(x) on the interval (-1/2, 1/2], since you are given the fact that the nth derivative of k is <= 10 on this interval then you can use 10 as the value for M.

Edit:

So the error for the approximation needs to be less than .1 = 1/10.  This means that you need the above error bound to be <= 1/10.  So you will just solve that inequality for n.  Which you can do by trying values of n.  For example, if n = 1 (a 1st degree Taylor polynomial, or linear approximation) then the error will be $10*(1/2)^2 / 2! = 10/8$ which is not <= 1/10, so n = 1 is not a good enough approximation, continue checking in this way for higher degree Taylor polynomials.

Comment: In your book, or [here,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) look up the Lagrange form of the remainder in Taylor's Theorem.

Comment: sorry but you guide me along this one , i still have no idea how to do this

Comment: Edited to provide more information.